# Point on axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I need to get plot like this:

[image]

But in my MWE node label and dot are hidden.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
ylabel={\footnotesize Enthalpy, $H$},
xlabel={\footnotesize Temperature, $T$},
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
ticks=none,
%y=1.7cm,
%x=1cm,
]
\addplot [mark=none,domain=0:1] {0.5*x + 0.25};
\node[label={180:{$H_0$}},circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] at (axis cs:0,0.25) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe add 'clip=false' to your axis options?